# Why does the value returned should be on the same line as the return statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The following doesn't work as I would expect it to:

```
function test()
{
  // Returns undefined, even though I thought it would return 1
  return
  1;
}
```

Apparently, the value should be on the same line: `return 1;`. Why can I write things like

```
// Assigns 1 to foo just fine
foo
=
1;
```

...but the `return` statement doesn't work the same way?

Comment: `=` isn't a legal statement in itself, so a semicolon couldn't be automatically inserted there. `return;`, on the other hand, is a valid statement, so it *can* be terminated by an implicit semicolon, leaving the `1;` statement hanging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behavior of 'return' statement in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723492/strange-behavior-of-return-statement-in-javascript)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi

Comment: @BoltClock I think it's more the other way round... according to the spec semi-colons are inserted when an *illegal* token is encountered.  So if it were illegal to follow `foo` with `=`, then a semi-colon would be inserted.  E.g., I think a semi-colon would probably be inserted in the case of `var <newline> =`, even thought the resulting program would still be invalid.

Comment: `return` is a bit of a different case, since it's a restricted production -- which doesn't apply to `foo = 1`

Answer (score 2):

It's explicitly part of the language spec. If it were not, there would *still* be `return` issues:

```
if (something())  return
counter = counter + 1;
```

Without the semicolon insertion rule, that missing semicolon would trigger behavior that's (I'd argue) just as bizarre as what happens now with `return` statements split across a newline.

Comment: +1 for illustrating the rationale behind making return a restricted production.  I knew it was one, but had only ever seen examples where this gives the wrong behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript automatically inserts a semicolon after the "return" statement if the return expression is not on the same line.

> JavaScript has a mechanism that tries to correct faulty programs by automatically inserting semicolons. Do not depend on this. It can mask more serious errors. It sometimes inserts semicolons in places where they are not welcome. Consider the consequences of semicolon insertion on the return statement. If a return statement returns a value, that value expression must begin on the same line as the return:

```
return
{
   status: true
};
```

> This appears to return an object containing a status member.
>   Unfortunately, semicolon insertion turns it into a statement that
>   returns undefined. There is no warning that semicolon insertion caused
>   the misinterpretation of the program. The problem can be avoided if
>   the { is placed at the end of the previous line and not at the
>   beginning of the next line:

```
return {
   status: true
};
```

Quoted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723492/strange-behavior-of-return-statement-in-javascript), citing *JavaScript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford. Copyright 2008 Yahoo! Inc., 978-0-596-51774-8*.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript will insert a semi-colon in certain cases to try to make an otherwise invalid program into a valid one.  In particular, a `return` statement is an example of what's called a "restricted production" -- you aren't allowed to have a line break after return before the value, so it gets transformed into `return;` and the following value becomes a separate statement.

In the case of

```
foo
=
1
```

this is not a restricted production, and furthermore neither `=` or `1` are illegal tokens in that position, so there's no attempt to insert a semi-colon at the end of the preceding line.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses semicolon insertion! For every line you forgot to close it with a semicolon JS will insert it automatically! In this case:

```
return // auto semicolon insertion
{ // that's fine
    1; // yey here's one
} // ok, np
// bye bye
```

This means in JavaScript the use of `{` opening bracket is not, like in other languages, by developer's choice. You have to follow the rules:

```
return {
    1;
}
```